# Data format updating table in MySql from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to modify a table data using a SQL statement

```
foreach (Words words in Words_DB.Records)
{
   string _IPAUS = words.IPAUS;
   string _IPAUK = words.IPAUK;
   query = "UPDATE Words SET IPAUK='" + _IPAUK + "',IPAUS='" + _IPAUS + "' WHERE WORD='" + words.Word + "'";
   command.Parameters.Clear();
   command.CommandText = query;
   //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAUK", _IPAUK);
   //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAUS", _IPAUS);
   //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WORD", words.Word);
   int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

A example of query is ***UPDATE Words SET IPAUK='ɑːd.vɑːk',IPAUS='ɑːrd.vɑːrk' WHERE WORD='aardvark'***
The problem is when a read the database data I receive :

[image]

But, when I use the MySql Tools to execute the Query the result is right.
What I am doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: You're concatenating raw string values. If `_IPAUK` contained `'; --` you'd lose all data in that column. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. In this case you're probably trying to pass Unicode data using ASCII syntax, resulting in mangled data. You started to use parameterized queries, as you should, but went back to the buggy raw SQL instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```cs
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Words SET IPAUK= @IPAUK, IPAUS= @IPAUS WHERE WORD= @Word;";

// Match these to the column type and length in the DB
command.Parameters.Add("@IPAUK", MySQlDbType.VarChar, 30);
command.Parameters.Add("@IPAUS", MySQlDbType.VarChar, 30);
command.Parameters.Add("@Word", MySQlDbType.VarChar, 30);

foreach (Words words in Words_DB.Records)
{
    command.Parameters["@IPAUK"].Value = words.IPAUK;
    command.Parameters["@IPAUS"].Value = words.IPAUS;
    command.Parameters["@Word"].Value = words.Word;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Notice how the above minimizes the work done in the loop, which should improve performance, while also **fixing** the *HUGE GAPING SECURITY ISSUE* in the question from using string concatenation to build the query.

Separately, I have the impression `Words_DB.Records` is the result of a prior query. It's highly likely you could eliminate this entire section completely by updating the prior query to also do the update in one operation on the server. Not only would that greatly reduce your code, it will likely *improve performance here by multiple orders of magnitude*.

Comment: In MySQL there's no need to avoid `AddWithvalues`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's only partly correct. There's no reason to avoid it due to parameter type mismatch, but that's not the reason behind the different use here. Instead, I used the `Add()` overload to avoid repeatedly clearing and re-adding new parameter objects. The trick is, the ADO.Net provider contract for the method still wants a type definition. May as well be accurate about it.

Answer (score 1):

The question concatenates raw input to generate a SQL query which exposes to SQL injection and bugs like this one. If `_IPAUK` contained `'; --` all the data in that column would be lost.

In this case it seems the code is trying to pass Unicode data using ASCII syntax, resulting in mangled data.

The solution to both SQL injection and conversion issues is to [use parameterized queries](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/basic-api/). In a parameterized query, the actual parameter values never become part of the query itself. The server compiles the SQL query into an execution plan and executes that using the parameter values.

```
await using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
await connection.OpenAsync();

// Insert some data
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Words SET IPAUK=@IPAUK,IPAUS=@IPAUS WHERE WORD=@Word";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IPAUK", words.IPAUK);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IPAUS", words.IPAUS);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Word", words.Word);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

The example uses the open source [MySQLConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) ADO.NET Driver instead of Oracle's somewhat ... buggy driver.

The code can be simplified even more by using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to construct the command, parameters and handle the connection automagically. Assuming `words` only has the IPAUK, IPAUS and Word properties, the code can be reduced to three lines :

```
var sql="UPDATE Words SET IPAUK=@IPAUK,IPAUS=@IPAUS WHERE WORD=@Word";
await using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql,words);
```

Dapper will construct a MySqlCommand, add parameters based on the properties of the parameter object (words), open the connection, execute the command and then close the connection

Comment: Hi, I resolved it using the parameter CharacterSet = "utf8" before to open de database.

Comment: @FranciscoLopez That's not helpful if you don't also FIX it to use parameterized queries (because otherwise it really is still horribly **broken**).

Comment: @FranciscoLopez that's no fix at all. If `IPAUK` contains `'; --` you still end up losing all data. There are worse cases: `'; DROP TABLE STUDENT; --` is a classic, there's even [an xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/327/) about this

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your helps.
This is my final code working properly.

```
string query = "UPDATE Words SET IPAUK=@IPAUK,IPAUS=@IPAUS WHERE WORD=@WORD";
var command = DatabaseConnection.MySql_Connection.CreateCommand();
try
{
  foreach (Words words in Words_DB.Records)
  {
     MySqlParameter IPAUSp = new MySqlParameter("@IPAUS", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 60);
     MySqlParameter IPAUKp = new MySqlParameter("@IPAUK", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 60);
     MySqlParameter WORD = new MySqlParameter("@WORD", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
     command.Parameters.Clear();
     command.CommandText = query;
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(IPAUKp.ToString(), words.IPAUK);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(IPAUSp.ToString(), words.IPAUS);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue(WORD.ToString(), words.Word);
     int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

}